# Selecting by a numeric id in grails geb

Tags: grails, selenium, geb, selenium-chromedriver

Using the chrome driver for selenium, I'm trying to select an element from my page by its id, which is numerical (ie 1000).

This fails, giving:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: findElements execution failed;
 SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.2.1', revision: '16551', time: '2012-04-11 21:42:35'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-33-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_09'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

However, if I change the id to be some string that is composed not exclusively by numbers (ie m1000), the selection works.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe because `ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z])`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: I didn't know that specification, the strange thing was that the selector worked on chrome's console. But that's surely the problem.
Please write the above comment as an answer so I can mark the question as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that it's because `ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z])`, see http://w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name